# I am not able to retrieve array values from List

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I want to retrieve values from List. But i can't get values from the list. I will call this method from another class by passing values to the method and add it in arraylist. Now when I try to retrieve the value nothing is returned.

```
public class No 
{
    private double km;
    private String stringvalue;

    List<String> k1=new ArrayList();
    List<String> k2=new ArrayList();

    public void clusterform(int i,String km1,String km2)
    {
        int val1=km1.length();
        int val2=km2.length();
        int centroid=i;

        if(val1>centroid)
        {
            if(val1>val2)
            {
                k1.add(km1);
                k2.add(km2);

                System.out.println("hi");
            }
            else
            {
                k2.add(km1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            k2.add(km1);
            k1.add(km2);
        }

        No n=new No ();

        n.call();
    }

    public void call()
    {
        Iterator getv = k1.iterator();
        while(getv.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(getv.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you actually add values to those array list?

Comment: when i call the clusterform method.

Comment: i changed the else to else if and no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is this Line:

```
No n=new No ();
n.String();
```

This is creating new object of `No` having its `ArrayList` `k1` initialized in such a way that it has size `0`. So `n.String()` method is printing nothing. You should instead call the `String()` method directly without creating the object in the following way :

```
String()
```

As side note I would suggest you to stick with java naming convention. For example the method name should start with small letter . class name should start with capital letter . And many more. Look at this [official tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) to know java naming conventions in details.

Comment: No, static does nothing here. You should call the method `String()` directly instead of calling it via object of `No`

Answer (score 0):

`k1` and `k2` are instance variables of the class `No`, so when you call `No n=new No ();` n becomes a new instance of the class with new(empty) lists. Probably you want to call the method String of the current instance of the class `No` instead of creating a new instance.